# Haskell: How to benchmark a computation accurately with deepseq/force

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, lazy-evaluation

I have a web server written in Haskell that computes some data in multiple steps.

I want to accurately measure and display how long each action takes.

In the presence of laziness, what is a good way to do this?

---

*Note that "benchmarking" is not quite the right terminology since I only only want to measure time in a production system and not sample many runs. I know that for that case I can use [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).*

Answer (score 4):

You can use `force` from `Control.DeepSeq` to fully evaluate a data structure (and thus demand and measure its computation).

One problem is that **forcing a large data structure takes some time itself!**

This is because a `deepseq` (used by `force`) will walk down your algebraic data type tree, visiting every node (but not doing anything with it).

When you perform only a cheap operation to each node, such as `map (*2) mylist`, and try to measure how long it takes, this overhead can suddenly become significant, messing up your measurements.

```hs
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Data.Time (diffUTCTime, getCurrentTime)


-- | Measures how long a computation takes, printing both the time and the
-- overhead of `force` to stdout. So it forces *twice*.
benchmarkForce :: NFData a => String -> IO a -> IO a
benchmarkForce msg action = do
    before <- getCurrentTime

    -- Force the first time to measure computation + forcing
    result <- evaluate . force =<< action

    after <- getCurrentTime

    -- Force again to see how long forcing itself takes
    _ <- evaluate . force $ result

    afterAgain <- getCurrentTime
    putStrLn $ msg ++ ": " ++ show (diffTimeMs before after) ++ " ms"
                   ++ " (force time: " ++ show (diffTimeMs after afterAgain) ++ " ms)"
    return result

    where
        -- Time difference `t2 - t1` in milliseconds
        diffTimeMs t1 t2 = realToFrac (t2 `diffUTCTime` t1) * 1000.0 :: Double
```

The first `evaluate . force` run will make sure your `action` and its return value are evaluated entirely.

By doing a second `force` run over the result, we can measure how much overhead it added to the first traversal.

This of course comes at the expense of two traversals; being able to measure how much time a `deepseq` wastes requires you to waste that time *twice*.

Here is an example to measure some pure functions with that:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do

    l <- benchmarkForce "create list" $
        return [1..10000000 :: Integer]

    _ <- benchmarkForce "double each list element" $
        return $ map (*2) l

    _ <- benchmarkForce "map id l" $
        return $ map id l

    return ()
```

(Of course it also works with functions in IO.)

The output:

```
create list: 1091.936 ms (force time: 71.33200000000001 ms)
double each list element: 1416.0569999999998 ms (force time: 96.808 ms)
map id l: 484.493 ms (force time: 67.232 ms)
```

As we can see, the `force` creates around 13% overhead in the `map id l` case.

Comment: My `chronograph` package can be used to measure evaluation times in the presence of laziness.  Unfortunately the `force` time is included in the measurement, and as you point out, it can be significant.